# Ajax-запрос на сервере выполняется, но потом открывается страница php-скрипта

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form

Помогите, пожалуйста.
В коде есть Ajax-запрос, который отправляет серверу данные из формы. Сервер данные получает, файл меняет, но echo не отправляет ответ, а открывается страница скрипта и echo выводит данные туда.

Код формы:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='change_form' method='post' action='ajax-for-saving.php'>
  <textarea id='filetext' name='filetext'>$content</textarea>
  <input type='hidden' name='filename' value='$pathToFile'>
  <input id='save_changes' type='submit' value='Сохранить' />
</form>
```

Код запроса:

```
$('#change_form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var changeForm = new FormData($('#change_form').get()[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: changeForm,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Код скрипта:

```
<?php
    echo file_put_contents($_POST['filename'], $_POST['filetext']);
```

Вот такая штука при нажатии на кнопку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не эксперт, но попробуйте в конце JS-функции добавить `return false;` Должно получить тип такого: `$('#change_form').on('submit', function(e) { ... return false; });`

Comment: У вас форма отправляет post серверу раньше чем сработает скрипт. Перепишите скрипт так, чтобы не было поста. Пост реализуйте в самом скрипте JS. Сервер сделал то, что вы просили. Он не причём (PHP).

Comment: @MrMEX Ошибаетесь, сперва идет слушатель потом отправка формы.

Comment: @MrMex, спасибо большое. Написала в url прямую ссылку, а из формы убрала. Заработало!

Comment: Сайт документации `file_put_contents` гласит `This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.` Так что вроде как все правильно, и файл записывается. проверьте `$pathToFile` в папке где `ajax-for-saving.php` находится.

Comment: @KostaB. точно!